# Only the first day is highlighted in Calendar, even if Event lasts for more than one day?

Tags: datetime

I am using [Pretty Calendar](https://drupal.org/project/pretty_calendar) module for the mini Calendar on my [website](http://etraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/). The problem is, it highlights only the first date of the event even if the event lasts for more than a day. For example, if you click on 5th May, you can see that it's a two days event and will finish on 6th May, but in the calendar, it highlights only 5th May.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks.